# AMA with UXPin, and you're all invited!

Tags: discussion

UXPin offered to do an Ask Me Anything with us on Graphic Design SE. We of course are excited and want to make this a big success. You're all invited!

https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/ama-with-uxpin-on-on-wednesday-october-2nd-4pm-6pm-gmt02